# Redefining ExtJS events and delegating to previous implementation

Tags: extjs, datagrid, event-handling, dom-events, extjs3

I've inherited a large ExtJS3 code base and there is a "base" override of Ext.grid.CellSelectionModel's beforecellselect.  I'm truncating huge swathes of code but this should provide the general idea:

```
Ext.override(Ext.grid.CellSelectionModel, {
    init:function() {
        Ext.grid.CellSelectionModel.superclass.init.apply(this, arguments);

        if (this.unselectableColumns || this.visuallyMimicRowSelection || this.colSpecificHandlers){
        this.on('beforecellselect', function(selModel, rowIndex, columnIndex){
            //etcetera
```

Subsequently however we are instantiating a CellSelectionModel, and specifying a beforecellselect listener on it as follows:

```
var sm = new Ext.grid.CellSelectionModel({
listeners: {
    beforecellselect : {
    fn: function(selModel, rowIndex, colIndex) {
            //etcetera
```

The issue is, from within the listener on the new CellSelectionModel instance, I also need to call the listener defined in the override.  Because ExtJS seems to preserve an array of like-named event listeners, I'm able to delegate as follows:

```
selModel.events.beforecellselect.listeners[1].fn.apply(selModel, arguments);
```

Ok, I know I shouldn't hard code the index.  But besides that is there a better, more ExtJS-y way, to do this?

Comment: Listeners get added (as can bee seen by the fact that the listener is in the listeners array that you mention), not replaced, so you shouldn't need to do anything to call the original listener.  All listeners should get called when the event fires.  There is probably something wrong with the override, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, if you know it'll be a function that will be used outside of the constructor,
I would suggest adding the event handler function as a method of the CellSelectionModel
instance, as shown below:

```
    Ext.override(Ext.grid.CellSelectionModel, {
        init:function() {
            Ext.grid.CellSelectionModel.superclass.init.apply(this, arguments);
            this.customBeforeCellSelect = function(selModel, rowIndex, colIndex) {
                // etcetera
            };
            if (this.unselectableColumns
                || this.visuallyMimicRowSelection
                || this.colSpecificHandlers) {
                this.on('beforecellselect', this.customBeforeCellSelect, this);
            }
    });

    var sm = new Ext.grid.CellSelectionModel({
        listeners: {
            beforecellselect : {
                fn: function(selModel, rowIndex, colIndex) {
                    selModel.customBeforeCellSelect.apply(selModel, arguments);
                },
                scope: sm
            }
        }
    });
```

However, keep in mind that you are attaching an event handler to the beforecellselect event in the overridden constructor, so if you call this event handler function again during beforecellselect in the specific instance `listeners`, then you will end up executing the same function twice in a row.

For efficiency considerations, you could move the custom handler to the prototype of `Ext.grid.CellSelectionModel`, i.e., instead of putting `customBeforeCellSelect` on the individual instance inside `init`. Do the following to make this possible:

```
    Ext.grid.CellSelectionModel.prototype.customerBeforeCellSelect =
        function(selModel, rowIndex, colIndex) {
            // etcetera
    };
```

You would add the above line after your `override` statement.

Comment: I'd suspected that was another approach and it's definitely less brittle.  This was my first half-week contracting however and I want to develop a level of confidence before they see me modifying their base overrides.  We'll see if anybody else answers with another way, but if not I should be accepting your answer in short order.

Comment: I forgot to take efficiency into account in original answer. I have updated the answer to account for that. The addition is at the bottom of the answer. :)